# Non Periodic, Deterministic Power Signals

Tags: transform, fourier

Any one know of work on non-periodic but deterministic power signals?  Now one member in this class would be the quasi periodic signals.  I wonder if there is a generalized Fourier analysis of non-periodic deterministic power signals.

Comment: Fourier analysis does apply to non-periodic signals... The spectrum is just continuous rather than discrete. The conditions of existence of the Fourier transform of a signal is that it has to be deterministic and can be integrated on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Also a generalisation of the Fourier transform is the Laplace transform (cf wikipedia)

Comment: I talk about a power signal here. Fourier transforms are only defined for some energy signals.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the signal
$$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \operatorname{rect}(t-n)\sin(2\pi nt)$$ which consists of $|n|$ periods of the signal $\sin(2\pi nt)$ in the interval $\left(n-\frac 12,n+\frac 12\right)$ for each integer $n$. Clearly, $x(t)$ is not periodic. Equally clearly, $x(t)$ is a power signal with average power $\frac 12$, and thus it is a nonperiodic but deterministic power signal. I leave it to the OP to determine whether the signal in question has a Fourier transform in the generalized sense (meaning it involves impulses) or not.

Comment: $x(t)$ is even continuous, but the derivatives are not at the $\operatorname{rect}(\cdot)$ boundaries.  how 'bout this one? :

$$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi(t-n)^2} \sin(2\pi nt)$$

Comment: These last two proposals seem to qualify for non-periodic power signals.  Now is there a generalized Fourier analysis to represent either or both of these?

Comment: **Short-Time Fourier Transform** (STFT) ?

Answer (score 0):

Chaotic Time Series are deterministic but not information preserving.  The term orbit is often used because they have cycles but are not periodic.

http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaostsa/